# Use JQuery to make color fade away, but keep boxes in place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a 16x16 grid. If you hover your mouse over a box, the box will turn pink. When you leave the box, the entire box disappears. I would like to make it so when you leave the box, the entire box stays intact, except the pink color fades away and is replaced with the original gray color after a second or so.

HTML:

```
<head>
<title>SketchPad</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
</head>

<body>
<h1> SketchPad </h1>

<div id="container">

</div>
 <script     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>        
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
text-align: center;
color: black;
}
tr, td, table {
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
background-color: gray;
margin: auto;
height: 25px;
width: 525px;
}
```

JS:

```
var rows=16;
var cols=16;

document.write("<table>");
for (i=0; i<rows; i++) {
document.write("<tr>");
  for (j=0; j<cols; j++) {
    document.write("<td>"+"</td>");
  }
document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");

$( "td").css("color", "red");
$("td").hover(function() {
$(this).css("background-color", "pink");
}, function () {
$(this).fadeOut("slow", function(){
});
});
```

Comment: I have played around with these responses and I am new so maybe I'm doing it wrong, but I either get no effect or the entire "td" elements disappear as I mouse out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

In order to have a cross-browser supported solution you could use animation trough javascript. Problem is that most of the properties that are not numeric can't be animated using plain jQuery (and `background-color` is one of those)

One of the options is to use [`jquery-color`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin

Example:

```
$("#go").click(function(){
    $("#block").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#abcdef"
    }, 1500 );
});
$("#sat").click(function(){
    $("#block").animate({
        backgroundColor: $.Color({ saturation: 0 })
    }, 1500 );
});
```

OTOH, transitions support is quite good on modern browsers so you'll be quite safe if you use a css only solution (IE9 and below doesn't support it)

Comment: is there a way to do this without using jquery-color plugin or css?

Comment: You can check what that plugin does and copy whatever is relevant for you. Another option is using jquery-ui. If you're already using it, then you don't need an extra library

Answer (score 1):

You could actually accomplish this all with css.

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}
tr, td, table {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: gray;
    margin: auto;
    height: 25px;
    width: 525px;
}
td {
    transition: 1s background-color;
}
td:hover {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5xvehb8o/

Comment: I should have mentioned, I need a JQuery or JS solution only.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.grid {
   height : 16px;
  width : 16px;
  border : solid 1px grey;
  background-color : grey;
  transition : 0.5s;
}

.grid:hover {  
  background-color : pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid"></div>
<br />
<div class="grid"></div>
```

Full CSS solution, with transition that can be modified in property `transition`.

Comment: You don't need two `transition` attributes. You can just have `transition: 0.5s` on `.grid`

Comment: Edited thank you for contrubuting @maxm.